# Wordpress CSV Importer Plugin, Import file from url instead of upload file from pc

Tags: wordpress, file, plugins, csv

The wordpress plugin csv importer http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/csv-importer/ works great for importing posts from csv. The plugin only supports browse file option to upload file from local pc while I want to upload file from file url.

Is this possible?

Can someone edit the plugin code so that it supports upload file from file url?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Just download the excel file from the URL to your PC and then upload it. Or is there something I'm missing here?

If you need this to repeat over and over, I'd disable that plugin and install [WP-All Plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-all-import/), which allows you to import from a URL.

For future reference, there is a [support forum for the csv-importer](http://wordpress.org/support/plugin/csv-importer) plugin.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question! I have tried wp all import plugin it works great on my shared hosting but when i installed it on vps server, the blank screen occurs after uploading the file. Can you let me know what causes this problem?

Comment: I don't know that answer, Zafar, but perhaps if you made a new question and stated that specifically, and used appropriate tags, somebody with knowledge in that area will see the question.